# How to open a default directory on a upload button in zul(ZK)?

Tags: java, user-interface, zk, zul

I am currently using the following tag in ZK(.zul) file.

```
< button id="uploadButton" upload="true" focus="true" onUpload="@command('uploadFile')"/ >
```

Whenever this button is clicked, the upload window that opens must show the same path everytime.
Let's say the path should be "C:\ABC\XYZ".

Is there any attribute of button tag that can help me doing this.
If not, kindly suggest some other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The upload window opens in the last path the last file was open...

Also by security reasons the web browser does not allow that you capture the complete path of a file, so you should not try to set a default path when you open the window...

Think this: you have a web browser and you want that when someone clicks the button the window shows the path "C:\ABC\XYC", but what happen if the computer that is running the program does not have that path (for example is a computer with some Linux distribution)? then actually does not have much sense make that the window shows you by default always the same path.

Comment: Yes I understand that concern.
But do not worry about operating systems and non-availability, I will code it likewise.